# Manage XML in PHP (Glossword)

Tags: php, xml, object

XML CODE:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<glossword version="1.8.11">
<line>
<term t1="L" t2="O" t3="B" uri="lobby" id="1187"><![CDATA[lobby]]></term>
    <defn>
        <abbr lang="025"><![CDATA[]]></abbr><![CDATA[Grupo de personas influyentes, organizado para presionar en favor de determinados intereses. La actividad se denomina lobbying y quien la practica lobbista.<br />Un ejemplo de lobby turístico en España es Exceltur; el Skal Club sería un lobby turístico internacional.]]>
        <syn><![CDATA[grupo de presión]]></syn>
        <see link="Exceltur"><![CDATA[Exceltur]]></see>
        <see link="Skal International"><![CDATA[Skal International]]></see>
    </defn>
    <defn>
        <abbr lang="025"><![CDATA[]]></abbr><![CDATA[Vestíbulo de un hotel y de otros establecimientos como cines, teatros, restaurantes, etc., especialmente si es grande.]]>
    <syn><![CDATA[hall, vestíbulo]]></syn>
        <see link="Tururu"><![CDATA[Tururu]]></see>
        <see link="Lalala"><![CDATA[Lalala]]></see>
    </defn>
</line>
</glossword>
```

Hello, I need help on managing this XML code in php. A quick summary of what this XML is about is that its about a certain "term" may have various definitions (defn) and each definition may have various synonyms (syn), seealso (see)...etc. I am not able to retrieve the data which are between the "(syn)" and "(see)" tags. This XML is formed by a (line) tag which is the "term" and which contains everything inside of this.

This is the code I am using to try to retrieve all the data in a certain tag:

```
foreach ($xml->line as $line){

    if($line->defn->see){

        foreach($line->defn->see as $seealso){ 

            $seealso = (array)$seealso;

            $model->addSeealso($idtermino,$seealso[0]);
     }
    }
 }
```

The issue is that Im only able to retrieve the data inbetween the first tag. For example  I am only able to get the "grupo de presión" but I cant retrieve in any way "hall, vestíbulo". This happens the same with the rest of the tags.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate over your `defn` nodes. Try something like this:

```
foreach ($xml->line as $line){ // Only if you can have several 'lines'
    foreach($line->defn as $defn){
        foreach($defn->see as $seealso){

            $seealso = (array)$seealso;

            $model->addSeealso($idtermino,$seealso[0]);
     }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks Arthur, this was very helpful. When I saw it I was like O_O why didnt I think of that?! Haha, thanks again!